# How to get visual studio diagnostic tools back?

Tags: visual-studio

[image]Accidently closed the windows and tool bar of diagnostic tools its already checked in Tools -> Options -> Debugging menu I just cant see memory useage graphic or diagnostic tool bar in debug

Comment: Debug --> show diagnostic tools or ctrl + alt + f2

Comment: Yeah I got it but dont show graphical memory useage window content is empty

Comment: You have to be debugging for it to show anything.

Comment: I cant see "Select Tools" bar ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Debug --> show diagnostic tools or ctrl + alt + f2

Comment: Debug, Windows, Show Diagnostic Tool on the menu. Anyway: thanks!